# Give an example in which $L(S\cap T)\neq L(S)\cap L(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

where $L(*)$ denotes the linear space spanned by $*$.

I know, and have proved, that $L(S\cap T)\nsubseteq L(S)\cap L(T)$. So I need to construct an example where the reverse containment does not hold, i.e. $L(S)\cap L(T) \subsetneq L(S\cap T)$; in other words, $\exists x$ such that $x\in L(S)$ and $x\in L(T)$ but $L\notin L(S\cap T)$

Since $x\in L(S)$, $\exists s_1,\dots, s_m \in S$ such that:
$$
x=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \alpha_ks_k
$$

and since $x\in L(T)$, $\exists t_1,\dots, t_n \in T$ such that:
$$
x=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \beta_k t_k
$$

Now I want at least one of the $s$'s and $t$'s (with a nonzero coefficient) to not be contained in $S\cap T$.But I'm having a hard time nailing down an example. In particular, I keep thinking of an intersection of two planes in 3D space, where equality in the title seems to always hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: in some real vector space of dimension greater than $0$, let $x\neq 0$. Then let $S = \{x\}$, $T=\{2x\}$. What are $L(S)$ and $L(T)$? What is $S\cap T$?

Comment: Your answer was really first since my first draft was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just $S = \{v\}$ and $T=\{2v\}$ for any nonzero vector $v$?

Comment: Because I am not a smart man :-)

Comment: Don't sel yourself short. Lots of mathematics seems obvious after you see it. That doesn't make it obvious in advance.